# Python Selenium webdr doesn't open browser with specified user and logs report that the chromedriver.exe couldn't be found

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

I have already checked if the directories are right, checked the chromedriver version to see if it is the right one for my browser and tried a list of different things to solve the problem and can't do it. Here is my code:

Obs: my imports are inside a core.py file with **init** in the directory where it is located.

```
# Imports
from core import *
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


# Configura registro de logging:
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

def logging_events():
    logging.debug("This is a debug message.")
    logging.info("This is an info message.")
    logging.warning("This is a warning message.")
    logging.error("This is an error message.")
    logging.critical("This is a critical message.")


# Configura drivers:
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(r"==user-data-dir=C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data")
options.add_argument(r"==profile-directory=Profile 1")
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")


def abre_url():
    chromedriver = "C:Users/MyUser/AppData/Local/SeleniumBasic/chromedriver.exe"
    service = Service(chromedriver)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

    # Abre o navegador:
    driver.get("https://mercadolivre.com")
    driver.maximize_window()
    time.sleep(5)    
    driver.quit()


logging_events()
abre_url()
```

Tried a lot of things that I can't remember now.`

Comment: I believe you want: service = webdriver.ChromeService(executable_path=chromedriver)  But I'd rename that var to something like chromedriverpath, just to make things clear.  You probably also want C:/Users/MyUser/AppData/Local/SeleniumBasic/chromedriver.exe  (left out a "/"?)